# Determining subgroup lattices and generators

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am confused about this question:

Suppose a is an element of order 24 in a group G. Determine the subgroup lattice of < a > and all the generators of < a >.

I understand generators and how to find them (say for Z_6 the generators are <1> and <5>) but I dont know how to find all the generators of an arbitrary element in a set given its order.

Anyhelp would be appreciated! Please keep the explanatinos relatively simple if you can!

Comment: "subgroup lattice of" ... $\langle a \rangle$? (Note, this was typeset using `$\langle a \rangle$`)

Comment: Yes, I didnt realize if I type < a > without the spaces between them it doesnt show up in my post.

Comment: Since $a$ is of order $24$, clearly $\langle a\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{24}$ (under addition modulo $24$).

Comment: So I just need to determine the subgroup lattice of Z_24?